# apt-cache show <package> <field> - show single field of a package

Tags: apt, bash, package-management, 22.04

As for:

```
$ dpkg -f <deb-file> <field>
```

there is something that likewise:

```
$ apt-cache show <package> <field>
```

returns me a field of a package?

For example, assuming I have discord already installed and its .deb archive in the current directory, I run the commands:

```
$ dpkg -f ./discord.deb Version
$ apt-cache show discord Version
```

Outputs I'd like:

```
0.0.27
0.0.27
```

Actual output:

```
0.0.27
... # discord package unwanted long output
N: Unable to locate package Version
```

I'd like a solution that makes use of the apt-cache or dpkg command itself.
In the absence of such a solution, then I accept the usual parser.

How do I solve?

EDIT 1:

I only want to display the installed version of a package.

Comment: `apt-cache show` takes only package-names as arguments ... So, `Version` will be looked up as a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show only the installed version of a package: *(and subsequently, this only works for installed packages)*

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}' --show <package>
```

To include a line break, just include a newline in the format string:

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}\n' --show <package>
```

Comment: `--showformat=` accepts "\" as an escape character ... So,  `--showformat='${Version}\n'` should work to feed a newline after the output.

Comment: Yes, you are right, "apt-cache show" would also show the version of a package not yet installed, which is not what I want. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: This is the solution I want, thank you.

Comment: For line break also this `dpkg-query -f '${Version}\n' -W <package>` is good.

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner extracts the version of a package:

```
apt-cache show packagename | awk '/^Version:/{print $2;}'
```

Comment: Some packages might show more than once in the output like e.g. apt and dpkg ... So, to print only the first reported version an `exit` action might be added like e.g. `apt-cache show apt | awk '/^Version:/{print $2; exit}'`